# MS SQL Server Reporting Server multiple query in one dataset

Tags: reporting-services

To have an expected result I must run these three queries 
for example:

1. `insert into tb1(a,b) select 1,2 // input data for stored procedure`
2. `exec sp // execute stored procedure`
3. `select * from tb2 // output of stored procedure`

and show tb2 data in report

How can it be performed in SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose all three steps within a single stored procedure which is called as your main dataset e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Reporting].[GetDataForMyReport]
    @Parameter1 [NVarChar](50),
    @Parameter2 [NVarChar](200)
AS
    -- Step 1
     INSERT INTO tbl1
            (a, b)
     VALUES (@Parameter1, @Parameter2)

    -- Step 2
    EXEC sp

    -- Step 3
     SELECT * -- Should explicitly declare the fields to return
       FROM tbl2
```

However, you should separate the concerns by having something else prepare the data, whilst the report only displays (and formats) the data.